# Can an Array be passed in an element-ui el-autocomplete callback?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, element-ui

I tried to use the `el-autocomplete` tag with the simplest version: an `Array` returned by the callback function ([JSFiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/zhej0n5a)).

```js
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      selectdusers: [],
      user: ''
    }
  },
  template: '<el-container>        <el-container style="margin-left: 15px; width: 150px">            <el-autocomplete                class="inline-input"                v-model="user"                :fetch-suggestions="filterUsers"                placeholder="add user"                @select="handleSelect"            ></el-autocomplete>            <el-button type="info" icon="el-icon-plus" click="addUser(user)">Add</el-button>        </el-container>    </el-container>',
  methods: {
    addUser(user) {
      this.selectedUsers.push(user)
      this.user = ''
    },
    filterUsers(user, cb) {
      console.log(user)
      cb(['qqq', 'zzz'])
      //return this.allusers.filter(x => _.includes(x.f+x.t, user))
    },
    handleSelect() {}
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#components-demo'
})
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.4.8/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/element-ui/2.4.7/index.js"></script>
<div id="components-demo">
  <button-counter></button-counter>
</div>
```

The suggestion box is visually empty, depite DevTools showing the expected elements in `<ElAutocompleteSuggestions>` →  `data` →  `suggestions`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What needs to be passed via the callback is an `Object` which must have a property called `value`.  This property holds what is displayed as the suggestion.

For the example above:

```
filterUsers(user, cb) {
      console.log(user)
      cb([{'value': 'qqq', 'whatever': 'djhjfh'}, {'value': 'zzz', 'whatever': 'uiuiiu'}])
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

For using Array instead of Object, you can use slot in autocomplete block

```
<el-autocomplete ...>
  <template slot-scope="{ item }">
    <div class="item">{{ item }}</div>
  </template>
</el-autocomplete>
```

Comment: This is the better answer, as it allows you to pass a straight flat array without issues